# Proximity checker for a ButtonGrid (like minefield game)

Tags: java, swing, methods

I'm writing a code for a treasure hunt game, a grid of buttons and one of them hide the treasure behind it. I want to ad a proximity checker: if the button clicked touch the  button with the treasure behind a message appear telling the player that he is near.
This is what i managed to write but i always get a mistake for the arrays going out of bound (this  happens because the last row and column aren't surrounded by buttons).

As you can see i put a lot of "if" to contain the chance of goig out of bound but it keeps happening. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `switch-cases` here.

```
 switch(grid){
   case treasure[x1][y1]:
     // your logic
        break;
     // other cases
   default:
     // default scenario 

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the length of the array before you try to access a row beyond it.   It appears that you are doing this for values that too low like this:

```
if (y1 < 0){
  y1 = 0;
}
```

But you need to have a similar check for values that are too high.

Alternatively,

This design could be much cleaner/simpler if you just passed in the X/Y location of the treasure. Instead of the actual JButtons.  Then you could just subtract the values to determine if you were close or not.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is to write a function to do the check for a match that also checks for the bounds. For example:

```
private boolean isTreasureAt(int x, int y) {
    if (x<0 || y<0 || x>width || y>height)
       return false;
    return treasure[x][y]; // need your correct checking logic here
}
```

Now you can just call isTreasureAt() for whatever co-ordinates you like and its always safe, no need to put range checks everywhere in your code.